# Getting Superfish jQuery plugin to work dynamically with several loops in PHP

Tags: mysql, jquery-plugins, php4, superfish

Hopefully some clever lad or ladette can help me figure out the logic for the follwoing code.

I have started to use superfish jquery plugin for my navigation and have got the code working fine and easily with static links, but when I try to change that to dynamic links I am having trouble getting the 2nd level  tag to work properly; to only show when 2nd level links are found and then only show once before the 2nd level links are written out from the database.

I hope I have made myself clear with the problem. Appologies if I havn't.

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
        <?php
            // A varible that increments on every loop of the below "while" statement
            $count == 0;

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM web_navbar_links WHERE link_parent='1' AND visible='1' ORDER BY position ASC");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                $parentID    = $row->id;
                $parentLevel = $row->slug;
                // Increment the counter varible by one
                $count++;

                echo "<li";
                    switch ($parentLevel) {
                        case "business":
                            echo " id='business'";
                            break;

                        case "education":
                            echo " id='education'";
                            break;

                        case "consumer":
                            echo " id='consumer'";
                            break;
                    }
                    echo "><a>".ucwords(trim($row->link_name))."</a>";

                    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM web_navbar_links WHERE link_child='1' AND parent_relationID='".$parentID."' AND visible='1' ORDER BY position ASC");
                    if ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
                        echo "<ul>"; //PROBLEM LIES HERE!! ATM THE <UL> WRITES ONCE BUT THE LOOP ONLY READS BACK THE LAST ENTRY FROMT HE db.
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
                            echo "<li><a href='http://". ROOT . ADMIN . SECTIONS . TEMPLATES . $row2->link_href."?".$row2->slug."=".$row2->slug."' title='".$row2->link_title."'>".$row2->link_name."</a>";
                                echo "<ul>";
                                    echo "<li><a href='#'>blah</a></li>";
                                echo "</ul>";
                            echo "</li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                echo "</li>";

                if ($count < 3) {
                    echo "<li class='breaker'></li>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies with this line:

```
if ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
```

This will move the record counter forwards, so the next time you call:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
```

`$row2` will have been populated with the second row. Since you are not using the first row anywhere between the 2 highlighted lines, you will lose it.

I suggest calling `mysql_num_rows($result2)` to get the number of rows returned instead of the first `mysql_fetch_object($result2)` in the if statement.

```
                $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM web_navbar_links WHERE link_child='1' AND parent_relationID='".$parentID."' AND visible='1' ORDER BY position ASC");
                if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                    echo "<ul>"; //PROBLEM LIES HERE!! ATM THE <UL> WRITES ONCE BUT THE LOOP ONLY READS BACK THE LAST ENTRY FROMT HE db.
                    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
                        echo "<li><a href='http://". ROOT . ADMIN . SECTIONS . TEMPLATES . $row2->link_href."?".$row2->slug."=".$row2->slug."' title='".$row2->link_title."'>".$row2->link_name."</a>";
                            echo "<ul>";
                                echo "<li><a href='#'>blah</a></li>";
                            echo "</ul>";
                        echo "</li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
```

Comment: perfect solution Gus, thank you for your knowledge and help :D